# Software for free netcafe (so computer tracking software)

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, multiple-workstations, cybercafe

I'm working in a small council. Here is some Ubuntu (with GNOME - no KDE) based workstations in our library. Using the computers is free now, before it was only /hour, what is not a high cost. I'm looking for a software, which can help me to manage the computers. How I mean:

- Notice the user after X minutes, to give her/his place for another user (if there are someone) = A text notice after X minutes (it would be better, if it gives a small signal too with the hardware speaker).
- Auto (& remote) shutdown of the workstations, (also disable them). [Auto power on is not required, because the users can push that power button, if they want to use the machines :D]
- Statistics and other infos about workstations, also their health status (I know `munin`, but included feature would be better). Eg: temps, SMART datas, login time, remaining time...
- (Updating all systems at once...)
- Free

Maybe, cafe softwares won't meet my requirements, I don't know how can I call that software for that situation. I can also appreciate multi software solution.

I read [this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Cafebuntu), but these softwares are focused on paying.

Comment: Good question +1

Comment: I am currently evaluating **Mkahawa Cyber Manager**, for Ubuntu 11.10 : http://mkahawa.sourceforge.net/  It looks quite good, although I am also looking for additional features not yet present.

Comment: I am also working on a product proposal for remote-access management. I would be very interested in your (more detailed) requirements ..

Answer (score 1):

For billing/timing, you might want to look at [Cafepilot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cafepilot/). It is free an open source software. It's currently aimed at people paying for their usage but you could give people tickets to use it (CP would think they're worth money but you'd just give them out for free).

For monitoring, remote-controlling and updating, check out [Canonical's Landscape tool](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape). It's currently quite expensive but might justify itself... You're always free to haggle with Canonical because your situation is somewhat different from the standard enterprise "seat" concept.

Otherwise you can loop together tools like Munin or Cacti with [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/). Puppet *is free* and is in the repositories but you probably want to look at the documentation on their main site. Note there is also a paid-for "Enterprise" version of Puppet that has a slightly augmented feature set.

Comment: Thanks Oli! I checked out every software. ***Cafepilot*** - Nice for paid, and ticket system cafes. I cant use it for timing only. :S **Landscape** - Very nice, I wrote to Canonical, I'm waiting for the answer. ***Puppet*** - Paid, for non-profit company it is only loss. I'm looking for free software!

Comment: Puppet is free and open source and is in the repos. Puppet Enterprise is what they charge for. And with Cafepilot could you not just set the pricing to $0.00? Also [see this](http://www.dijitanix.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=11:how-do-i-use-cafepilot-in-a-post-paid-environment&catid=1:cafepilot&Itemid=8). You could easily adapt that to give people one-off tickets (for free) that expire... So you can manage the timing still using fake transactions.

Comment: Oh, right, the ***Puppet*** is free. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'll take a look at it again (It is still not so clear, how it works), 'cos Canonical's answer still haven't received. ***Cafepilot*** - I firstly tried with $0 cost, but I couldn't log in with that: "you have zero credit". Other try: 0 mins, $1 = unlimited time. X mins, $1 = no credit recharge, account is usable only once. Ticket printing gives me more work, what is painful. So sorry, but Cafepilot is not for that place :S

Comment: If I undesrtood Oli's idea, you could use Cafepilot:

set the hourly rate of to (say) $1.

if you want to give a user half an hour of usage, just "credit" them with 50 cents